# My seed for arc4random_Uniform is bigger than UInt32 limit.?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My seed for arc4random_Uniform is bigger than UInt32 limit. What do I do?

Comment: The arc4random function do not have a seed. Are you looking for something like this: [Swift: Random number for 64-bit integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549830/swift-random-number-for-64-bit-integers) ?

Comment: Or do you mean the `upper_bound`?

Comment: I have closed the question as a duplicate because I assume that that is what you are looking for. If I am completely wrong then please leave a comment or update your question, and I will reopen it again.