# Overflow when converting from UInt32 to Int

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm having a really weird issue with Swift/Xcode (not really sure where the source lies, to be honest).

I have to following code:

```
extension Int {
    func random(min : Int = 0, max : Int = Int(UInt32.max - 1)) {
        return min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1)))
    }
}
```

When I build this code in Xcode, it works perfectly fine. When I try to build it using `xcodebuild` though, the compiler gives me the following error:

```
integer overflows when converted from 'UInt32' to 'Int'

    public static func random(min : Int = 0, max : Int = Int(UInt32.max - 1)) -> Int {
```

Which is weird, since the values of `Int.max` and `UInt32.max` are no where close.

I'm using Xcode 7.0 beta 5 for compilation if it is any help...'cause I'm absolutely stumped.

Comment: If you are going from Int to UInt32 there isn't a problem.  But you are trying to go from UInt32 to Int will cause a issue.

Comment: @BlackFrog: From Int to UInt32 can be a problem on 64-bit architectures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error occurs if you compile for a 32-bit device (e.g. iPhone 5),
because `Int` is then a *signed* 32-bit integer, and `UInt32.max - 1`
outside of its range.

Another problem is the calculation of `UInt32(max - min + 1)`,
which can crash at runtime due to an overflow, e.g. if you call

```
random(min : Int.min, max : Int.max)
```

See [How can I generate large, ranged random numbers in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391577/how-can-i-generate-large-ranged-random-numbers-in-swift) for a possible solution to avoid
overflows when generating random numbers for arbitrary ranges.