# Turn off Xcode's unused variable warnings while typing

Tags: swift, xcode7, compiler-warnings

I'm sick to death of Xcode's prolific use of live "unused variable" warnings while I am typing. I keep thinking I have an error in my syntax, stop what I'm doing, check the warning, only to see it's an unused variable warning.

[image]

Of course it's unused, I *just* typed it!

I don't mind the compile-time unused variable warnings, those are very useful, but I hate the live warnings as I'm typing code.

Is there any way I can turn off this warning completely everywhere, either app-wide or for an entire project?

Comment: I advise  you to ignore them. Even if you know why the warning is there, it doesn't mean it's not useful. Note that this IS a compile-time warning. The files get compiled while typing.

Comment: It must be possible to distinguish the types of compiles, though, and disable the warning only for IDE autoindex-type compiles.

Comment: I have an old MacBook you can buy. By the time it realises you haven't used the variable, you've typed the rest of the function. Problem solved.

Comment: @StevenFisher Why? It's logical they both use exactly the same settings.

Comment: @Sulthan Why would you think that? If the doc compiler uses slightly different settings, why wouldn't the indexer?

Answer (score 17):

It seems as of currently, we cannot suppress specific warnings in the way  `#pragma clang diagnostic ...` could be used for obj-C. See e.g. the following thread

- [How to suppress a specific warning in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516244/how-to-suppress-a-specific-warning-in-swift)

---

There is possible to disable *all interactive warnings* globally, by disabling ***Show live issues***, from ***Xcode -> Preferences: Tab General***. This, however, in excess of disabling all live warnings, also disable live errors, so something I presume you wouldn't want to resort to.

---

[Build warnings] You can turn off custom build warnings project-wide as follows:

- Select your project in the navigator, and choose tab ***Build Settings***. Find ***Apple LLVM 7.0 - Warnings - All Languages***, and disable the warnings for ***Unused Values*** and ***Unused Variables***.

[image]

Comment: I think he's asking how to turn these off while typing only, not while building: "I don't mind the compile-time unused variable warnings, those are useful, but I HATE the live warnings as I'm typing code."

Comment: And unfortunately, even disabling this does not seem to affect the live warnings.

Comment: I think dfri's is the only legal way possible.

Comment: I realized this only affect build warnings, not the interactive ones. Don't know if it's possible to customly disable the latter ones.

Comment: Current version of Swift (3.0) does not have toggleable warnings. Also not all of **Apple LLVM 7.0 - Warnings - All Languages** are implemented at all. That is why disabling or enabling them won't give any effect on Swift code.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov this is an slightly older Q&A, and the answer covers XCode 7; Xcode 8 was yet to be released at the time of the question. I noticed that your total number of downvotes are the double amount of your total numbers of upvotes (very uncommon negative-reinforcement ratio). Consider bringing positive feedback to the answerers of the site (which answer by the own free good will), rather than wildly shooting downvotes at each and every answer you pass by.

Comment: the only solution i found is to write ```_ = ...//some code with unused result``` - you can add it to your answer

Answer (score 2):

On my version (Xcode 10.2.1), it seems as if disabling live warnings only disables warnings, not all errors as others have said. So, I would think this exact answer addresses the original post quite well:

`Xcode > Preferences > General > Issues: [x] Show live issues`

Uncheck "`Show live issues`".  No more constant warnings as you type new code.