# Swift 3.0 Result of call is unused

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am writing in swift 3.0

I have this code which gives me the warning result of the call is unused

```swift
public override init(){
    super.init()
}
            
public init(annotations: [MKAnnotation]){
    super.init()
    addAnnotations(annotations:  annotations)        
}
            
public func setAnnotations(annotations:[MKAnnotation]){
    tree = nil
    addAnnotations(annotations: annotations)
}
            
public func addAnnotations(annotations:[MKAnnotation]){
    if tree == nil {
        tree = AKQuadTree()
    }
                
    lock.lock()
    for annotation in annotations {
// The warning occurs at this line
        tree!.insertAnnotation(annotation: annotation)
    }
    lock.unlock()
}
```

I have tried using this method in another class but it still gives me the error the code for insert Annotation is above

```swift
func insertAnnotation(annotation:MKAnnotation) -> Bool {
    return insertAnnotation(annotation: annotation, toNode:rootNode!)
}
        
func insertAnnotation(annotation:MKAnnotation, toNode node:AKQuadTreeNode) -> Bool {
            
    if !AKQuadTreeNode.AKBoundingBoxContainsCoordinate(box: node.boundingBox!, coordinate: annotation.coordinate) {
        return false
    }
            
    if node.count < nodeCapacity {
        node.annotations.append(annotation)
        node.count += 1
        return true
    }
            
    if node.isLeaf() {
        node.subdivide()
    }
            
    if insertAnnotation(annotation: annotation, toNode:node.northEast!) {
        return true
    }
            
    if insertAnnotation(annotation: annotation, toNode:node.northWest!) {
        return true
    }
            
    if insertAnnotation(annotation: annotation, toNode:node.southEast!) {
        return true
    }
            
    if insertAnnotation(annotation: annotation, toNode:node.southWest!) {
        return true
    }
    
    return false
}
```

I have tried many methods but just doesn't work but in swift 2.2 it works fine any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: It's telling you the truth.  Your function returns a `Bool`, and you ignore that fact with your invocation.  If that's what you mean to do, and you want to shut up the warning, change the invocation to `_ = tree!.insertAnnotation(annotation: annotation)`.

Comment: See this thread: [Result of call to "myFunction" is unused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939573/result-of-call-to-myfunction-is-unused).

Comment: @discardableResult http://stackoverflow.com/a/27261991/2303865

Answer (score 583):

You are getting this issue because the function you are calling returns a value but you are ignoring the result.

There are two ways to solve this issue:

1. Ignore the result by adding `_ =` in front of the function call
2. Add `@discardableResult` to the declaration of the function to silence the compiler

Comment: On one hand you can put `@discardableResult` once and fix them all, but on other hand you can't make it with you pods, so you have to use 1st solution.

Comment: What do you mean by that Ossir? You cannot use it with CocoaPods?

Comment: @gran_profaci You might be using someone else's code (through Pods or somewhere else) and cannot change the code interface definition, in which case "_ =" is the only solution.