# Swift Compiler Warning : Result of call to 'save(defaults:)' is unused

Tags: ios, swift, warnings, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

So my table view is not loading anything and I think it's because of this warning that I get. It saids the save function is not being used so how can it load something that is not saved. What I am saving is the indexPath and Section of the row that the user selected via a button action in the row.

Warning:

> Result of call to 'save(defaults:)' is unused

Code:

```
func saveSorting(_ dataIdBlock: (Any) -> String) {

    guard let items = self.items else { return }

    for (section, rows) in items.enumerated() {
        for (row, item) in rows.enumerated() {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            let dataId = dataIdBlock(item)
            let ordering = DataHandling(dataId: dataId, indexPath: indexPath)

            // Warning is here
            ordering.save(defaults: indexPath.defaultsKey)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NSCoder Class for DataHandling / ordering.save

```
DataHandling.swift

class DataHandling: NSObject, NSCoding {

var indexPath: IndexPath?
var dataId: String?

init(dataId: String, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    super.init()
    self.dataId = dataId
    self.indexPath = indexPath
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    if let dataId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "dataId") as? String {
        self.dataId = dataId
    }

    if let indexPath = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "indexPath") as? IndexPath {
        self.indexPath = indexPath
    }

}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(dataId, forKey: "dataId")
    aCoder.encode(indexPath, forKey: "indexPath")
}

func save(defaults box: String) -> Bool {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let savedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)
    defaults.set(savedData, forKey: box)
    return defaults.synchronize()

}

convenience init?(defaults box: String) {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let data = defaults.object(forKey: box) as? Data,
        let obj = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? DataHandling,
        let dataId = obj.dataId,
        let indexPath = obj.indexPath {
        self.init(dataId: dataId, indexPath: indexPath)
    } else {
        return nil
    }

}

class func allSavedOrdering(_ maxRows: Int) -> [Int: [DataHandling]] {

    var result: [Int: [DataHandling]] = [:]
    for section in 0...1 {
        var rows: [DataHandling] = []
        for row in 0..<maxRows {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            if let ordering = DataHandling(defaults: indexPath.defaultsKey) {
                rows.append(ordering)
            }
            rows.sort(by: { $0.indexPath! < $1.indexPath! })
        }
        result[section] = rows
    }

    return result

  }

}
```

Other code I'm using:

```
// Number of Rows in Section
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.items?[section].count ?? 0
}

// Number of Sections
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return self.items?.count ?? 0
}
```

Saving it with:

```
saveSorting() { "\($0)" }
```

Loading it in ViewDidLoad:

```
func fetchData() {

    // Load Data from Server to testArray
    retrieveData()

    // request from remote or local
    data = [testArray]

    // Update the items to first section has 0 elements,
    // and place all data in section 1
    items = [[], data ?? []]

    // apply ordering
    applySorting() { "\($0)" }

    // save ordering
    saveSorting() { "\($0)" }

    // refresh the table view
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Loading Code:

```
// Loading
func applySorting(_ dataIdBlock: (Any) -> String) {

    // get all saved ordering
    guard let data = self.data else { return }
    let ordering = DataHandling.allSavedOrdering(data.count)

    var result: [[Any]] = [[], []]

    for (section, ordering) in ordering {
        guard section <= 1 else { continue } // make sure the section is 0 or 1
        let rows = data.filter({ obj -> Bool in
            return ordering.index(where: { $0.dataId == .some(dataIdBlock(obj)) }) != nil
        })
        result[section] = rows
    }

    self.items = result
}
```

Comment: Please always [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Result+of+call+to+is+unused) before posting.

Comment: [@discardableResult](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0047-nonvoid-warn.md) can suppress your warning

Comment: Better use `@discardableResult` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192751/swift-3-0-result-of-call-is-unused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DataHandling` instance's `save(defaults:)` function technically returns a value, even if you don't use it. To silence this warning, assign it to `_` to signify that you don't intend to use the result value, e.g.:

```
_ = ordering.save(defaults: indexPath.defaultsKey)
```

or

```
let _ = ordering.save(defaults: indexPath.defaultsKey)
```

Just to be clear, this is almost definitely not why your tableview is not loading data. It should be pretty insignificant. The `indexPath.defaultsKey` *is* being saved (assuming the API works).

Comment: So am I loading it correctly if its being saved? Any idea on why the table doesn't load? I would appreciate the help.

Comment: It's hard to say since I'm not familiar with this "`DataHandling`" API. Have you thrown in some breakpoints to see where the code is and isn't reaching? I wouldn't be surprised if there are some parse errors considering all of the archiving / unarchiving and coding / decoding logic. It's hard to debug something like this without running the code locally. @BroSimple

Comment: I included the DataHandling code if you need it, I could try using breakpoints. I have the project on github if you dont mind helping me out? You can receive the credit for this question and another one I have open regarding the same issue?

Comment: I don't, different questions, other one was a general question around the empty table, this one is about the warning

Comment: If you have the github URL better to post it as an edit to the question itself

Comment: You're right I posted it at the bottom, I thought it was better to post the code