# Return a boolean value from a function in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, boolean, func

I cannot figure how the new first label proposal for Swift 3.0 applies to returnTypes with Bool:

```
var firstString = "string"
var secondString = "thing"

func areTheStringsAnagrams(first: String, second: String) -> Bool {
    return first.characters.sorted() == second.characters.sorted()
}

areTheStringsAnagrams(first: firstString, second: secondString)
```

Why is the call to the function unused?

The error is:

`/swift-execution/Sources/main.swift:11:1: warning: result of call to 'areTheStringsAnagrams(first:second:)' is unused
areTheStringsAnagrams(first: firstString, second: secondString)
^                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

Although a previous questions focused on `NSLayoutConstraints` (i.e., [Result of call to [myFunction] is unused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939573/result-of-call-to-myfunction-is-unused)) in a comparison to Objective-C, the present question is narrower in that it focuses exclusively on function calls with a `returnType` of `Bool` in Swift 3.0.

Comment: What is the error you get from the compiler?

Comment: This code does compile and work properly. What is this question about?

Comment: Which function is unused?

Comment: I cannot figure out what the problem with this code is. I ran it both in a Playground as well as in IBM's Swift Playground but function call is unused. I am stumped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Result of call to \[myFunction\] is unused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939573/result-of-call-to-myfunction-is-unused)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything with the result.

You can assign the result:

```
let anagrams = areTheStringsAnagrams(first: firstString, second: secondString)
```

If you don't need the result, you have two options. You can either assign to `_`

```
_ = areTheStringsAnagrams(first: firstString, second: secondString)
```

or you could mark the function with `@discardableResult`

```
@discardableResult
func areTheStringsAnagrams(first: String, second: String) -> Bool {
    return first.characters.sorted() == second.characters.sorted()
}
```

In this case, I wouldn't do the last option since if you ignore the result, what was the point of calling it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you that you are invoking a function that returns a value but you are not using that value. This could be an error on the developer side so the compiler shows a warning message.