# Is there a way to use functions with same names but different return types?

Tags: swift, function, methods, declaration

My intention is the following:

My first function:

```
public mutating func replaceSubstringInRange(_ range: CountableClosedRange<Int>, withString string: String) -> String
```

that I can use it in a context of `print()` for example.

And my second:

```
public mutating func replaceSubstringInRange(_ range: CountableClosedRange<Int>, withString string: String) -> Void
```

just for modifying something.

I know that there is a different function signature needed, but is there any better way?

Comment: No, but you can use a function returning `String` as if it were `Void`.

Comment: That sounds perfect. How can I realize this?

Comment: Just call it, and do not assign the result to any variable. Swift will let you do it.

Comment: But then appears the warning: "Result of call to ... is unused".

Comment: You'll also want to mark it as `@discardableResult` to indicate that the return value doesn't have to be used (compare [Result of call to \[myFunction\] is unused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37939573/2976878)). But I wouldn't advise having a `mutating` method that also returns the mutated instance – the usage of the method is clearer if you call it on a separate line, and then work with the mutated instance afterwards. Otherwise it may appear at first glance that the method is creating a new string, rather than mutating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define two functions with identical parameter types without creating an ambiguity, but you can call a function returning a value as if it were `Void`. This generates a warning, which you can silence by designating your function result discardable:

```
@discardableResult
public mutating func replaceSubstringInRange(_ range: CountableClosedRange<Int>, withString string: String) -> String {
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can have two functions with same name, same parameters and different return type. But if you call that function and do not provide any clue to compiler which function of the two to call, then it gives ambiguity error,

Examples:

```
func a() -> String {
    return "a"
}

func a() -> Void {
    print("test")
}


var s: String;
s = a()
// here the output of a is getting fetched to a variable of type string,
// and hence compiler understands you want to call a() which returns string

var d: Void = a() // this will call a which returns void

a() // this will give error Ambiguous use of 'a()'
```

Comment: This should be recognised as the valid answer. function signature includes the returning type as well.