# Swift - Unexpected error in simple if statement

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift so this might turn out to be very simple, but I'll ask you anyway since I can't figure it out:

I was playing on the Playground and thought I'd write some lines of code in order to do this: generate a random number between two given values (a,b).
If, for example, a = 5  and  b = 20, a random number between 5 and 20 is supposed to be generated.
But I get an unexpected error! I wrote these lines of code

```
var a = UInt32()
var b = UInt32()
var randomNumberInBetween = Int()

a = 5
b = 20

if (b - a) > 0 {
    randomNumberInBetween = Int(arc4random_uniform(b - a) + a)
} else {
    print("error", terminator: "")
}
```

Now:

If b > a (so that (b-a)>0 ) it works just fine.

If b = a it prints "error", so it works correctly.

BUT if a > b, so that (b-a)<0, it gives  this error : "Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_l386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)."

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZD10.png)

My question is: If (b-a)<0 shouldn't it just run the "else" part of the if statement and just print "error" ? Why does this error occur?

Comment: Just replace `if b - a > 0` by `if b > a` ...

Comment: @MartinR lol that worked, thanks a lot!!

Comment: if your question has been answerred, please accept an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UInt32` version of `-` has the signature: `(UInt32, UInt32) -> UInt32`.

7 - 9 is -2.

You can't express -2 with an unsigned type such as `UInt32`.

Try something like:

```
func random(inRange range: Range<Int>) -> Int {
    return range.lowerBound + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)))
}

func random(inRange range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int {
    return range.lowerBound + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound + 1)))
}

print(random(inRange: 1..<10))
```

Comment: Your suggested function can (theoretically) crash as well, because `UInt32(max - min + 1)` can overflow. So either you have to check that as a precondition, or make it work with "large" integers, as e.g. in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391577/how-can-i-generate-large-ranged-random-numbers-in-swift.

Comment: @AMomchilov I think you mean `7-9 is -2`.