# Generate random number of certain amount of digits

Tags: swift, random, range

Hy,

I have a very Basic Question which is :

How can i create a random number with 20 digits no floats no negatives (basically an Int) in Swift ?

Thanks for all answers XD

Comment: Can the leading digit be a 0?

Comment: Yea shure that wouldnt mater

Comment: Here are some solutions for 64-bit random integers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549830/swift-random-number-for-64-bit-integers, but note that UInt64 is not large enough for an arbitrary integer with 20 decimal digits (10^20 > 2^64).

Comment: The largest number that can be represented in 64 bits is: 18446744073709551616 and that is insufficient. 20 decimal digits would require 67-bits. How do you propose holding the number?

Comment: @HuRiXD Did you really want a number that was 20 digits? Or was that an example number picked at random that happens to make computer scientists nervous?

Comment: It was picket sort of random 20 would be nice but if 14 or 18 makes it easier if would also work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some pseudocode that should do what you want.

```
generateRandomNumber(20)
func generateRandomNumber(int numDigits){
   var place = 1
   var finalNumber = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < numDigits; i++){
      place *= 10
      var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(10)
      finalNumber += randomNumber * place
  }
  return finalNumber
}
```

Its pretty simple. You generate 20 random numbers, and multiply them by the respective tens, hundredths, thousands... place that they should be on. This way you will guarantee a number of the correct size, but will randomly generate the number that will be used in each place.

**Update**

As said in the comments you will most likely get an overflow exception with a number this long, so you'll have to be creative in how you'd like to store the number (String, ect...) but I merely wanted to show you a simple way to generate a number with a guaranteed digit length. Also, given the current code there is a small chance your leading number could be 0 so you should protect against that as well.

Comment: This will probably abort with an overflow exception in Swift.

Comment: Probably true... in that case store it in a String like a UUID and parse it back into a number wherever you need it.

Comment: Parse it back to a number where? Into a uint128_t?

Comment: Good point @zaph. I'm not sure why he would need a number that's 20 digits. But perhaps the question was more geared towards generating a number with a certain amount of digits and 20 was a random number that is unusual. The title asked how to generate a number of digits, and the post is where the mystical number 20 appeared.

Answer (score 15):

### Step 1

First of all we need an extension of `Int` to generate a random number in a range.

```
extension Int {
    init(_ range: Range<Int> ) {
        let delta = range.startIndex < 0 ? abs(range.startIndex) : 0
        let min = UInt32(range.startIndex + delta)
        let max = UInt32(range.endIndex   + delta)
        self.init(Int(min + arc4random_uniform(max - min)) - delta)
    }
}
```

This can be used this way:

```
Int(0...9) // 4 or 1 or 1...
Int(10...99) // 90 or 33 or 11
Int(100...999) // 200 or 333 or 893
```

### Step 2

Now we need a function that receive the number of digits requested, calculates the range of the random number and finally does invoke the new initializer of `Int`.

```
func random(digits:Int) -> Int {
    let min = Int(pow(Double(10), Double(digits-1))) - 1
    let max = Int(pow(Double(10), Double(digits))) - 1
    return Int(min...max)
}
```

### Test

```
random(1) // 8
random(2) // 12
random(3) // 829
random(4) // 2374
```

Comment: Love the idea to do it in an extension! +1

Comment: Actually here I used the extension only to generate a random number in a range. But you are right, we could transform the `random` function as an extension of `UInt`.

Comment: How will you represent the number 36893488147419103232? (that requires more than 64-bits and still only has 20 decimal digits.

Comment: Again, this cannot work with 20 digits. Also note that your `UInt32(..)` calculations can *overflow* on a 64-bit platform if the range includes negative numbers (which is not the case for *this* question). Try `let rnd = Int(Int.min + 10 ..< Int.max - 10)` (it crashes). Here is a safe way to produce random numbers in an arbitrary integer range: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391577/how-can-i-generate-large-ranged-random-numbers-in-swift.

Comment: In Swift 4, getting error "cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(CountableClosedRange<Int>)'"

Comment: @LucaAngeletti I checked your Step2 solution by printing 1000 times and it gives me 9 wrong numbers.
for _ in 1...1000 { print(random(digits: 2)) }.

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 5:  Simple Solution**

```
func random(digits:Int) -> String {
    var number = String()
    for _ in 1...digits {
       number += "\(Int.random(in: 1...9))"
    }
    return number
}

print(random(digits: 1)) //3
print(random(digits: 2)) //59
print(random(digits: 3)) //926
```

**Note** It will return value in `String`, if you need `Int` value then you can do like this

```
let number = Int(random(digits: 1)) ?? 0
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create a string number then convert the number to your required number.

```
func generateRandomDigits(_ digitNumber: Int) -> String {
    var number = ""
    for i in 0..<digitNumber {
        var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(10)
        while randomNumber == 0 && i == 0 {
            randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(10)
        }
        number += "\(randomNumber)"
    }
    return number
}

print(Int(generateRandomDigits(3)))
```

for 20 digit you can use Double instead of Int

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3
appzyourlifz's answer updated to Swift 3

Step 1:

```
extension Int {
init(_ range: Range<Int> ) {
    let delta = range.lowerBound < 0 ? abs(range.lowerBound) : 0
    let min = UInt32(range.lowerBound + delta)
    let max = UInt32(range.upperBound   + delta)
    self.init(Int(min + arc4random_uniform(max - min)) - delta)
    }
}
```

Step 2:

```
func randomNumberWith(digits:Int) -> Int {
    let min = Int(pow(Double(10), Double(digits-1))) - 1
    let max = Int(pow(Double(10), Double(digits))) - 1
    return Int(Range(uncheckedBounds: (min, max)))
}
```

Usage:

```
randomNumberWith(digits:4) // 2271
randomNumberWith(digits:8) // 65273410
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is 18 decimal digits in a UInt64:

(Swift 3)

```
let sz: UInt32 = 1000000000
let ms: UInt64   = UInt64(arc4random_uniform(sz))
let ls: UInt64   = UInt64(arc4random_uniform(sz))
let digits: UInt64 = ms * UInt64(sz) + ls

print(String(format:"18 digits: %018llu", digits)) // Print with leading 0s.
```

16 decimal digits with leading digit 1..9 in a UInt64:

```
let sz: UInt64 = 100000000
let ld: UInt64 = UInt64(arc4random_uniform(9)+1)
let ms: UInt64 = UInt64(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(sz/10)))
let ls: UInt64 = UInt64(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(sz)))
let digits: UInt64 = ld * (sz*sz/10) + (ms * sz) + ls

print(String(format:"16 digits: %llu", digits))
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. How to get 16 decimal digits?

Comment: Updated the answer for 16 digits where the leading digit must be 1-9.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 version of Unome's validate response plus :

- Guard it against overflow and 0 digit number
- Adding support for Linux's device because "arc4random*" functions don't exit

With linux device don't forgot to do

```
#if os(Linux)
    srandom(UInt32(time(nil)))
#endif
```

**only** once before calling *random*.

```
/// This function generate a random number of type Int with the given digits number
///
/// - Parameter digit: the number of digit
/// - Returns: the ramdom generate number or nil if wrong parameter
func randomNumber(with digit: Int) -> Int? {

    guard 0 < digit, digit < 20 else { // 0 digit number don't exist and 20 digit Int are to big
        return nil
    }

    /// The final ramdom generate Int
    var finalNumber : Int = 0;

    for i in 1...digit {

        /// The new generated number which will be add to the final number
        var randomOperator : Int = 0

        repeat {
            #if os(Linux)
                randomOperator = Int(random() % 9) * Int(powf(10, Float(i - 1)))
            #else
                randomOperator = Int(arc4random_uniform(9)) * Int(powf(10, Float(i - 1)))
            #endif

        } while Double(randomOperator + finalNumber) > Double(Int.max) // Verification to be sure to don't overflow Int max size

        finalNumber += randomOperator
    }

    return finalNumber
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage in single extension:

```
Int.randomNumberWith(digits: 6) // 453532
```

```
extension Int {
    init(_ range: Range<Int> ) {
        let delta = range.startIndex < 0 ? abs(range.startIndex) : 0
        let min = UInt32(range.startIndex + delta)
        let max = UInt32(range.endIndex   + delta)
        self.init(Int(min + arc4random_uniform(max - min)) - delta)
    }
    
    static func randomNumberWith(digits: Int) -> Int {
        let min = Int(pow(Double(10), Double(digits-1))) - 1
        let max = Int(pow(Double(10), Double(digits))) - 1
        return Int(Range(uncheckedBounds: (min, max)))
    }
}
```